# Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    article.*,
    activity.*
FROM
    article,
    activity
    LEFT JOIN articlecontent ON article.id = articlecontent.articleID
    LEFT JOIN activitycontent ON activity.id = activitycontent.activityID 
WHERE
    articlecontent.languageID = 'no'
    AND
    activitycontent.languageID = 'no' 
ORDER BY
    sortDate DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Which returns the following error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'article.id' in 'on clause'`

What could I do to fix it?

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit `JOIN` queries - instead you should always use explicit joins.

Comment: What is the relationship between `article` and `activity`? The query is meaningless without a defined JOIN condition between them. Right now your query doesn't have one.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix the old school comma operator syntax for join operations with the newer JOIN keyword syntax.

There doesn't appear to be any condition that links `article` and `activity`. So the query will generate a cross product (a Cartesian product)... each and every row in `article` will be matched to each and every row in `activity`. If that's the desired set, we can add the `CROSS` keyword as documentation for the future reader. Otherwise, add some condition.

Also, the predicate in the WHERE clause requiring a non-null value for a column from activitycontent 
(i.e. `activitycontent.languageID = 'no'`) negates the outerness of the LEFT JOIN, rendering it equivalent to an INNER JOIN. (With that condition in the WHERE clause, then omitting the `LEFT` keyword won't change the result.) If we need an outer join, we can relocate that predicate to the ON clause of the outer join.)

```
SELECT article.*
     , activity.*
  FROM article
  JOIN activity
    ON 1=1       -- condition that links article to activity should go here
  LEFT
  JOIN articlecontent
    ON articlecontent.articleID = article.id
   AND articlecontent.languageID = 'no'
  LEFT
  JOIN activitycontent
    ON activitycontent.activityID = activity.id
   AND activitycontent.languageID = 'no'
 ORDER BY article.sortDate DESC
 LIMIT 3
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Looking at the query in my answer, the outer joins to the `activitycontent` table and the `articlecontent` table look pointless. Those would only serve to potentially produce duplicate rows. If the intent is to restrict the rows returned, then make those into INNER JOINs by removing the LEFT keyword.

```
SELECT article.*
     , activity.*
  FROM article
 CROSS
  JOIN activity
  JOIN articlecontent
    ON articlecontent.articleID = article.id
   AND articlecontent.languageID = 'no'
  JOIN activitycontent
    ON activitycontent.activityID = activity.id
   AND activitycontent.languageID = 'no'
 ORDER BY article.sortDate DESC
 LIMIT 3
```

Without an actual, concrete specification (preferably including example data and an expected result), we're left guessing what result is supposed to be returned by the query.

It's just not possible to suggest a query that will return the result we are after... if we don't know what result we are after.

Comment: The point of the query is to loop through a content that's very similar in 2 different tables - article and activity - they're supposed to mix. One other thing is the sortDate, with that I now get `Column 'sortDate' in order clause is ambiguous` - that's another problem I didn't point out in my question, but already knew would pop up - is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: I was going to mention qualifying *all* column references in the query. prefix `sortDate` with the name of the table, just like the other column references are qualified.  For example  `ORDER BY article.sortDate`. If the intent is to produce a cross product, then remove the `ON 1=1` and add the keyword `CROSS` as an aid to the future reader/maintainer... **`FROM article CROSS JOIN activity`**. (The CROSS keyword is optional in MySQL. It doesn't affect the result. Other databases require the keyword when an ON clause is omitted.)

Comment: Without a more concreted specification (perferably including example data, and an expected resultset), it's not possible to suggest a query. Looking at the query in my answer, those LEFT JOIN operations seem pointless, they would only serve to potentially return duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your query makes no sense.  In addition to the comma, the `left join`s are turned into inner joins by the `where` clause.  Then you are selecting from the first two tables -- the left joins would choose all rows with no filtering.

This "fixes" the query:

```
SELECT article.*, activity.*
FROM article CROSS JOIN
     activity INNER JOIN
     articlecontent
     ON article.id = articlecontent.articleID INNER JOIN
     activitycontent
     ON activity.id = activitycontent.activityID 
WHERE articlecontent.languageID = 'no' AND
      activitycontent.languageID = 'no' 
ORDER BY sortDate DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

I'm not confident that this does anything useful.